# Open list of files in vim to specific lines

Tags: vim

I know about vins command line operator but I need a version that works on multiple files .

For instance I have a stack trace file and would like it to open all of the files to the line in a different buffer

Comment: Maybe a silly question, but why not use a debugger for that?

Comment: There's a number of [solutions on so](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15364634/how-to-open-multiple-files-at-different-lines-with-vim)

Answer (score 2):

With the [file:line - Allows you to open file:line and it does the right thing](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2184) plugin, you can use

```
$ vim foo.c:123 bar.c:456
```

Answer (score 2):

To go to line 3 on file1.txt and line 4 on file2.txt I do this:

```
vim -c ":e file1.txt|:3|:e file2.txt|:4"
```

Answer (score 1):

This will open the specified files and to to the specified line (to wit: line 123) in all specified files:

```
vim -p +'tabdo 123' /path/to/somefile /path/to/some/otherfile
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# search for searchable string in all the files
vim -c ':vimgrep /searchable/ `find . -type f \| grep -v .git \| grep -v .log`'

" if those bellow are set in ~/.vimrc you cycle back and forth with F5 and F6
" :vimgrep /$to-srch/ `find . -type f -name '*.pm' -o -name '*.pl'`
" F5 should find the next occurrence after vimgrep
map <F5> :cp!<CR>

" F6 should find the previous occurrence after vimgrep
map <F6> :cn!<CR>
```

From a [.vimrc](https://github.com/YordanGeorgiev/ysg-confs/blob/master/.vimrc.host-name) with more settings and explanations